# Compare SQL Varchar field to SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two databases for which I want to compare a `varchar50AllowNulls` column in one to a `TextNotNull` column in the other.

What I find is that when I have a value in the varchar column and an empty string in the text column, my Access query to these linked tables works.

However when I have an empty string in the `varchar` and a value in the text column, it does not work.

I cannot find any topics that seems to address this. I could ask the developer to change the text to `varchar`, but thought best if I can resolve using SQL.

My guess is that I need to cast or trim, but my efforts have not been successful.

```
SELECT 
    A.EQNUM, A.[Varchar50AllowNulls], B.EQNUM, B.[TextNotAllowNulls]
FROM 
    A 
INNER JOIN 
    B ON A.EQNUM = B.EQNUM
WHERE 
    ((A.[Varchar50AllowNulls] <> B.[TextNotAllowNulls]));
```

Comment: what do you mean, "works"? You're not comparing equality (`=`), you're comparing INEQUALITY (`<>`), so the only results you'll get are where the two fields have different values. And note that null cannot ever be equal or unequal to anything, including itself. null is poisonous and the result of (most) operations involving null will produce null as a result.

Answer (score 2):

The logic for your `WHERE` clause below is that you want to remove a record when the nullable `VARCHAR` column is *not* equal to the non nullable `TEXT` column.  If `Varchar50AllowNulls` is *not* `NULL`, then your original condition using `<>` was already checking for this.  However, when `Varchar50AllowNulls` *is* `NULL` then `<>` won't work, because comparing any value against `NULL` is unknown.  Instead, since `TextNotAllowNulls` cannot be `NULL`, then whenever `Varchar50AllowNulls` is `NULL` you want to remove this record, regardless of the value of the `TEXT` column.

```
SELECT A.EQNUM,
       A.[Varchar50AllowNulls],
       B.EQNUM,
       B.[TextNotAllowNulls]
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.EQNUM = B.EQNUM
WHERE A.[Varchar50AllowNulls] <> B.[TextNotAllowNulls] OR
      A.[Varchar50AllowNulls] IS NULL
```

Comment: Solved...  Perfect, and I now understand the logic.  I actually tried something very similar but obviously not with the simplicity of your add.  Thank you for the lesson Tim.

Comment: @DaleArp - if this works for you please mark this an answer- it helps to clear the unanswered question queue - and acknowledges the fact that the person answered your question